# How to Access Files in ASP.NET Web Forms Application via Virtual Directory on Network Location?

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, file-exists, virtual-directory

Processing files in a virtual directory under IIS is successful when the client is on the server but fails when the client is on another PC on the network.

We have an ASP.NET Web Forms application (c#) that accesses TIF files via a virtual directory pointing at a network location. For example, virtual directory named `corpfiles` points at `\\FileServer\share`. The application is an intranet site using Windows Authentication, and the users have access to the file share.

The web site is passed a number of URLs for TIF files on a page, e.g., `./corpfiles/file1.tif`, `./corpfiles/file2.tif`, etc. For each URL that ends in `.tif` the page (this code is in the `page.aspx.cs` code behind file):

1. Gets the physical file path: `var filePath = Server.MapPath(docUrl);`
2. Ensures the file exists: `if (File.Exists(filePath))`
3. Converts the TIF to an in-memory PDF and presents it on the web page.

This all works testing from Visual Studio 2022 (I added the virtual directory to my `applicationhost.config` file for IIS Express), and when testing from the server hosting the site. However, the File.Exists call fails when the site is connected to from another box on the network.

The filePath returned by Server.MapPath is valid; the user is able to access the original file directly using it.

If I don't try to access the file and just past the original URL to the user they are able to download the `.tif` file without trouble. This isn't very useful since viewing the file outside of the application is clunky, but it does demonstrate they have access to the original file share.

Is this a multi-hop authentication issue? We have tried supplying specific credentials on the virtual directory and using the client's credentials.

What am I missing?

Comment: What account does your app pool run as, and does that account have permissions to that fileshare?

Comment: To learn if you hit a double hop issue, ask your domain administrators for assistance. They can also show you the solution if confirmed.

Comment: You can contact your system administrator to try to configure delegation, which will allow a server to forward a user's credentials to another server.

Comment: The app pool is running under a domain account that is able to access the files. It seems like a delegation issue since everything works if I use the site on the server, which is a classic symptom of multi-hop delegation problems. This site has been set up at clients where we have to delegate creds to SQL Server if it resides on another box, and I have used the DelegConfig tool (https://blogs.iis.net/brian-murphy-booth/delegconfig-delegation-configuration-reporting-tool) to get things right, but it no longer works (it was released in 2009 and the tool threw exceptions when I tried it here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the delegation of credentials was not properly configured. The Domain Admin had to:

1. Create an SPN for the file server: CIFS/FILESERVER
2. Ensure the service account could delegate using Kerberos only to the new SPN.
3. Give the service account access to the FILESERVER.

The real-time conversion of TIFs to PDFs now works with the result being the users can view the PDFs within the application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, keep in mind the following:

Any time code behind touches or uses a file: a plain full legal path name is used.

Any time a URL resolves to a file, then it not code behind, and you are NOT using a full Windows path name.

But, with code behind, yes, a full regular Windows file name and path is used and CAN be used.

So, what does the above mean?

You actually don't need to map a virtual folder to the web site, but can use 100% code behind to retrieve such files.

This actually is often a VERY good approach, since then no valid URL's to folders are mapped though the web site. That enhances security by a LARGE margin.

So, it is not clear at all why the `file.Exists()` is failing, but do keep in mind that is code behind, so File.Exists("full legal Windows path and file name goes here") is required.

So, if you need to say present some files (or even folders + files) to the user?

Then you don't actually have to map or use a virtual folder.

However, the web site WILL most certainly need rights to those folders on the network - but the users don't!

So, say I wanted to display some files (or folders).
And say I don't want a mapped virtual folder (since that is a big security hole anyway).

So, remember, code behind DOES NOT use the IIS security model! In other words, you don't even have to have/use a web.config for that virtual folder, and you don't even need the virtual folder!

So, there are 2 issues left here to deal with:

First up, how you going to display the files to the user.

A simple GridView is fine if this is just one folder, or better yet consider a TreeView if you have a bunch of folders (say nested folders).

The next issue is security. Remember, code behind does NOT care about the logged on user - it is the web site user that will (or will not) have rights to those files. This is due to for this discussion we are going to DUMP the use of a virtual folder, and NOT use IIS folder mapping here (and that means we by-pass IIS security here).

This DOES mean the web server has to be on that network, and this DOES mean the web server will need rights to that folder - could even be some other server or network storage device (only requirement is those folders/files are on the same network that running the web server).

Of course, we will have to "setup" the context of the web site. As I pointed out, code behind DOES NOT care about the logged on user, and the security enforced by IIS is 100% ignored.

You don't mention if the web server is part of your company domain or not. Let's assume it is NOT, and again a good idea to NOT have the web server as part of your company network domain anyway for reasons of security.

However, this THEN does mean that you need a user on the web server, one that you can create - and create a user that is NOT a domain user.

You will THEN need to create a user (same name, same password) on the server with the folders in question. (And again, NOT a domain user, but a user created on that server with the folders + files).

Now, all you have to do is ensure that the code behind runs with this user context.

You can right click on the app-pool, and choose this:

[image]

So, we set the app pool to run now as this local created user (called Web in this example).

And we assume you now gone to the server with the shared folders, and ALSO add this user to that server (again, same name, same password).

So, now, without a virtual folder, without caring about who logged into the site, you can now with code behind get/grab/see/use/browse those files with code behind. However, web users can not in ANY way enter a URL or in ANY way get or grab a file. So, it is a nice secure setup.

The only part left is for you to present some type of UI here.

So, say a tree view, might be like this:

And any file you click on, it will be downloaded, but we use code behind - NOT a legal or valid URL path name! (when I say legal path name, I mean a NON virtual and NON URL path name here!).

So, we get say this:

[image]

Now, in above I do have check box(s) for each file - probably should not.

So, when user clicks on a file, then I do this:

```
    protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // download this  file clicked on
        // user MIGHT click on a node, so not a file,
        // so first check if file extension

        string sFileWithPath = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
        FileInfo MyFile = new FileInfo(sFileWithPath);

        if (File.Exists(sFileWithPath))
        {
            string sFileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(sFileWithPath);
            string sMineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(sFileWithPath);
            FileInfo sFinfo = new FileInfo(sFileWithPath); // get lengh of file

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = sMineType;
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", sFinfo.Length.ToString());

            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFileNameOnly);
            Response.TransmitFile(sFileWithPath);
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Print("user clicked on folder");
        }
    }
```

So, code behind is free to get folders, traverse folders, and all such code is using plain valid full Windows path names. You never have to use any `Server.MapPath()`, since we never using a valid URL, and translating into a full Windows file name (that's what `Server.MapPath` does) is not required any more.

So, your file.exists should work, but I would for several reasons, and one being security. I would not map those folders to the server using a Virtual folder, but ONLY use code behind, and by-pass IIS and such file mapping.

The code to display folders in a tree view: it is in fact not even recursive, and is quite easy to write.

Comment: I did say, "The application is an intranet site using Windows Authentication." Regardless, the site and the files are on the same domain. It is not exposed to the Internet. The site is running under an app pool with domain credentials, and the domain account has access to the file share. The application already presents the files to the user using a tabbed view since there are only a handful, but we want to convert the occasional TIF to a PDF real-time so the user can view it within the site without a 3rd party TIF viewer.Pretty sure it is a delegation problem at this point.

Comment: Ok, then enter a domain user with rights for the app pool as I suggested above. And the concept of code behind vs that of IIS still 100% applies to the above narrative. In other words, if things like file.exist fail, then either your not using a valid windows file and path name, or that the IISS_USER which is the user that app_Pool runs under does not have sufficient rights to those files (hence change the app_pool to run as a domain user/logon as suggested.